# How can I use array with awk in Linux

Tags: linux, arrays, awk

```
INFO #my-service# #add# id=67986324423 isTrial=true
INFO #my-service# #add# id=43536343643 isTrial=false
INFO #my-service# #add# id=43634636365 isTrial=true
INFO #my-service# #add# id=67986324423 isTrial=true
INFO #my-service# #delete# id=43634636365 isTrial=true
INFO #my-service# #delete# id=56543435355 isTrial=false
```

I want to count the lines which are having unique ids with `#add#` attribute in them & having `isTrial=true`.

This is my current solution and I want to know why my array is not printing

```
BEGIN { print "Begin Processing of various Records"}

{if($3~"add" && $5~"true")
   {
   ++i; 
   if($4 not in arr){arr[i]=$4;++j} 
   }
  {print $0}
}

 END {print "Process Complete:--------"j}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test to see if the fourth field is not already in the array, like so:

```
BEGIN {
    print "Begin Processing of various Records"
}

$3 ~ /add/ && $5 ~ /true/ && !a[$4]++ {

    i++
    print
}

END {
    print "Process Complete. Records found:", i
}
```

Results:

```
Begin Processing of various Records
INFO #my-service# #add# id=67986324423 isTrial=true
INFO #my-service# #add# id=43634636365 isTrial=true
Process Complete. Records found: 2
```

[Here's some info](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Basics.html#Array-Basics) that may interest you. HTH.

---

As per comments below, you could also do this:

```
BEGIN {
    print "Begin Processing of various Records"
}

$3 ~ /add/ && $5 ~ /true/ && !a[$4] {

    a[$4]++
    print 
}

END {
    print "Process Complete. Records found:", length(a)
}
```

Note that this is very different from:

```
BEGIN {
    print "Begin Processing of various Records"
}

$3 ~ /add/ && $5 ~ /true/ && !a[$4] {

    # See the line below. I may not have made it clear in the comments that
    # you can indeed add things to an array without assigning the key a
    # value. However, in this case, this line of code will fail because our
    # test above (!a[$4]) is testing for an absence of value associated
    # with that key. And the line below is never assigning a value to the key!
    # So it just won't work.

    a[$4]


    # Technically, you don't need to increment the value of the key, this would
    # also work, if you uncomment the line:

    # a[$1]=1

    print 
}

END {
    print "Process Complete. Records found:", length(a)
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what does this means `!a[$4]++`

Comment: Sure. It simply means: 'If field 4 is not (!) in an array (called a), add it to the array, incrementing the key's value by one (++)'. Does that make sense? The fourth field is the key to the array.

Comment: I didn't get the ++ part , i didn't get what part is adding the $4 to array and what part is incrementing the key

Comment: So, `$4` is the key. And `a[$4]` would be the value of that key. As soon as you write `a[$4]++` the key is 'put' into the array and assigned a value of one. We use `++` to [increment](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-8) the value of the key, so that each time the key is found, the key's value is increased by one. You may also find [this](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-22) a worthwhile read. Please let me know if more explanation is needed. Cheers!

Comment: I still didn't get it. why we need to increment the value and for what purpose we are using that value. what diff it makes if value does not increment. All we are concerned is the if key is in array or not. we have no intial value of `a['id=3213313']`. now by incrementing you mean `a['id=313123' + 1]` or `a['id='313123'] = 0 + 1`

Comment: You need to increment the key's value, because if you don't, the key will never be added to the array. In your script, a test of `!a[$4]` would always return true, because the key is never being added to the array. All it's doing is checking if it's not already in the array. In your example, you'd want to write: `a["id=313123"]+=1` which is the same as `a["id=313123"]++`. Here the key is `id=313123` and the value will be incremented by one.

Comment: you are saying that key will never br added to array if we don't incraement. I have 2 questions . 1) is there any other way to add the key to array like `a.addkey(keyname)` without incrementing. 2)  by incrementing u just mean to say that the array has some non zero value so that it gets added to array. so does it mean that setting `a[$4] = 5` will add it to array

Comment: All `awk` arrays are associative. So you can assign a key a name; `a[$4]="a name"`, a variable; `a[$4]=$0` or a number; `a[$4]=5`. Once you've assigned something, it's in the array. You can use the `delete()` function to remove keys of your choosing or the entire array. See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Delete.html)

Comment: , thanks buddy , it now gets cleared. The things is awk does 10 things in 2 or 3 characters , which becomes difficult to grasp

Comment: Ok cool, but (I may not have been 100% clear) don't forget you can add things to an array without a value, simply like: `a[$4]`. I've added an explanation as to why it won't work for you in your script. Please see the edit I made.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep '#add#.*isTrial=true' input | sed 's/[^=]*=\([^ ]*\).*/\1/' | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: Actually i am learning awk , so i would like awk solution to learn. thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

One way using awk:

```
$ awk '$3 ~ /add/ && $5 ~ /true/{sub(/.*=/,"",$4);a[$4]++;}END{for (i in a)print i, a[i];}' file
43634636365 1
67986324423 2
```

Regarding your solution:

1. When you use the contains(`~`) operator, the pattern should always be provided in slashes(`//`), not directly in double quotes.
2. When you check `$4 not in arr`, it checks for $4 in the array keys, whereas you are populating $4 as an array value `arr[i]=$4`.

Comment: Can you correct my script , so that i see how far i was from the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$5~/isTrial=true/ && $3~/#add#/{a[$4]}END{for(i in a){count++}print count}'
```

tested [here](http://ideone.com/r1ao9p)